# Is there a term for quoted language in a poem?

Tags: poetry, literary-device

In Wyatt's *Whoso List to Hount*, there is a (fictional) piece of writing quoted.  Here are the three lines that display this:

> There is written, her fair neck round about:/
> '*Noli me tangere* for Caesar's I am,/
> And wild for to hold though I seem tame.'

Is there a literary term for this kind of quote or separate voice in poetry?

Comment: Are you aware of the significance of [noli me tangere?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noli_me_tangere) As it is supposed to be engraved on a collar, it could be called an _inscription_ or _legend_.

Comment: Such a well-known Latin phrase embedded in an English-language poem might also be referred to as a [Latin] *tag,* but I know of no special term for when the speaker of a poem quotes someone or something else. Perhaps the phenomenon is just too common to warrant naming. There is a special term *(ecphrasis)* for a poem's description of a work of visual art, that being a somewhat rarer thing; but the principal function of such rarefied terms of art would seem to be for showing off erudition.